# High order functions assignation

Tags: swift, generics

I'm learning about High Order functions in Swift (like .map .filter .reduce...) and generics types.

Here is my function :

```
func max<T: Comparable>(_ array: [T]) -> T {
    var max = 0 as! T

    for value in array {
        if value > max { max = value }
    }

    return max
}
```

How can I replace my for loop with high order function to get the same result ?

Im looking to do something like this (or better) :

```
max = array.map { $0 > max ? $0 : max }
```

Comment: `max([-3, -2])` return `0` with your code, and  `max(["a", "b"]` crashes.

Comment: You're right! this method need to some serious fixes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that your approach for the "initial value" and the forced
cast

```
var max = 0 as! T
```

has two problems:

- It will crash for arrays not containing integers, e.g. `max(["a", "b"]`).
- Even for integer arrays, it is wrong if all array elements are
  negative, e.g. `max([-2, -3])` should be `-2` and not zero.

So you better choose the first array element as initial value instead
of the "forced zero".

That leads to the next question: What if the array
is empty? There are two valid approaches: You can *require* that the
function is called with a non-empty array (and document that
precondition):

```
/// Compute the maximal element in an array.
///
/// - Returns: The maximal element.
///
/// - Note: The array must not be empty.
func max<T: Comparable>(_ array: [T]) -> T {
    precondition(!array.isEmpty, "`max` called with empty array")

    var max = array[0]
    for value in array {
        if value > max { max = value }
    }
    return max
}
```

Or (as also suggested in the other answers) make the return value 
optional:

```
/// Compute the maximal element in an array.
///
/// - Returns: `nil` if the array is empty, and the maximal element otherwise.
func max<T: Comparable>(_ array: [T]) -> T? {

    guard var max = array.first else { return nil }
    for value in array {
        if value > max { max = value }
    }
    return max
}
```

Both approaches can be implemented with `reduce()`.
The first one would be

```
/// Compute the maximal element in an array.
///
/// - Returns: The maximal element.
///
/// - Note: The array must not be empty.
func max<T: Comparable>(_ array: [T]) -> T {
    precondition(!array.isEmpty, "`max` called with empty array")
    return array.reduce(array[0]) { $0 > $1 ? $0 : $1 }
}
```

and the second one

```
/// Compute the maximal element in an array.
///
/// - Returns: `nil` if the array is empty, and the maximal element otherwise.
func max<T: Comparable>(_ array: [T]) -> T? {
    guard let first = array.first else { return nil }
    return array.reduce(first) { $0 > $1 ? $0 : $1 }
}
```

This can be further shortened using the `flatMap()` method
of `Optional`:

```
/// Compute the maximal element in an array.
///
/// - Returns: `nil` if the array is empty, and the maximal element otherwise.
func max<T: Comparable>(_ array: [T]) -> T? {
    return array.first.flatMap { array.reduce($0) { $0 > $1 ? $0 : $1 } }
}
```

Finally you can use the existing

```
func max<T : Comparable>(_ x: T, _ y: T) -> T
```

function instead of a literal closure in all of the above examples, e.g.

```
/// Compute the maximal element in an array.
///
/// - Returns: `nil` if the array is empty, and the maximal element otherwise.
func max<T: Comparable>(_ array: [T]) -> T? {
    return array.first.flatMap { array.reduce($0, max) }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Reduce!

```
return array.reduce(nil)
{
    (max: T?, current: T) -> T? in
    guard let max = max else { return current }
    return max > current ? max : current
}
```

That will return an optional but that is probably sensible given you might pass in an empty array.

Of course there is also this

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1688806-max

The implication of tyour question is that this is a learning exercise. So here is a generalisation of the solution that makes use of higher order functions. Note that the Swft Strandard Library already contains a function that does this.

```
extension Array 
{
     func pickOne(choose: (Element, Element) -> Element) -> Element?
     {
         return self.reduce(nil)
         {
             (bestSoFar: Element?, current: Element) -> Element? in
             guard let bestSoFar = bestSoFar else { return current }
             return choose(bestSoFar, current)
         }
     }
}
```

So the functionality of max is now defined like this:

```
array.pickOne { $0 > $1 ? $0 : $1 }
```

and min would be

```
array.pickOne { $0 < $1 ? $0 : $1 }
```

Answer (score 1):

For Ints you would want to use `reduce` for this like so:

```
// Reduce with initial value the first value of the array if available,
// or 0 otherwise
let max = array.reduce(array.first ?? 0) { (max, newValue) -> T in
    return newValue > max ? newValue : max 
}
```

UPDATE

You want JeremyP's answer for a proper handling of all Comparable!

Comment: And if array is `[-1, -2]`?

Comment: I considered a down vote, but the question has the same bug.

Comment: Also what if 0 is not convertible to T?

Comment: @JeremyP You are right, I see now that I assumed it was an Int, updated the answer accordingly. Your answer is the correct one as it handles Comparable without assumptions.

Comment: My first attempt at the answer had the same problem(s) I used 0, then I thought, what about negative numbers, so I wrote `Int.min` and then I thought, it's not necessarily an `Int`.